# What is the difference between a++ and a+1?

Tags: c++, for-loop, post-increment, pre-increment

I was writing a small piece of code wherein I had to increment value of a variable 'j' if the condition matched.

```
for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++){//input and base are of type string
        for(int j=0;j<base.length();j++){
            if(input[i]==base[j])input[i]=base[j+1];
        }
    }
cout<<input;
```

When I executed the code, for every input I got a blank string as an output. But if I used ++j instead of j+1, the code seems to work fine. What am I missing here ?
Also, the code for j-1 as well as --j works fine. The only problem I face is with j+1. Is it something related to precedence of operators ?

Comment: j++ and j+= 1; are the same thing.  j+1 does not increment j but adds one and then throws away the sum so j never gets incremented.

Comment: Well, if it was just `j+1` no wonder it didnt work. It should be `j=j+1`

Comment: If j+1 didnt work then how j-1 did ?

Comment: @agr_vin Your code invokes undefined behavior (out-of-bounds access) on the last iteration if the last items are equal.  So given that, your code doesn't "work" with `j+1`.  So your observations are due to an incorrectly written loop using `j+1`, not because of `++j` or any other variation.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Okay I will try to correct my loop's boundary conditions. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

There are two diferences related to these expressions: what will be the value of the expression and whether `a` will be changed. For expression

```
a + 1
```

its value is the sum of operands `a` and `1` and `a` itself will not be changed.

For expression

```
a++
```

its value is the value of `a` before the increment and `a` will be changed. For example if `a` is defined the following way

```
int a = 0;
```

and there is another variable `b` defined like

```
int b;
```

then after statement

```
b = a++
```

`b` will be equal to `0` and `a` will be equal to 1. while after statement

```
b = a + 1;
```

`b` will be equal `1` and `a` will not be changed that is it will be equal as before to `0`.

If you mean expression

```
a += 1;
```

then if fact it has the same result as expression `a + 1` except that a will be changed.

Take into account that `a++` is unsequenced relative to other subexpressions in an expression.

Expression

```
a += 1;
```

is similar to expression

```
++a;
```

So the difference between `a++` and `a += 1` is the same as between `a++` and `++a`. Also take into account that the result of `a++` is `rvalue` (you may not assign any value to the expression) while the result of `a += 1` is `lvalue` (you may assign a value to the expression like `( a += 1 ) += 1;`)

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int a=10,b=10;
    cout<<"a++ is \n "<<a++;
    cout<<"\n++b is\n "<<++b;
}
```

Output:

```
"a++ is
    10
"++b is   
    11
```

Answer (score -2):

`j++;` is j = j + 1. It is post increment operator. Value of j will increase after other operation of expression completes.

`j+1`, is you are adding one to value of j, but it will not affect j's value.